# Problema con reportes Crystal Repots al conectar con servidor

Tags: sql, vb.net, wpf, crystal-reports

Tengo un problema al querer generar reportes de una base de datos que se encuentra en un servidor, lo que sucede es que cuando realizo pruebas locales, los reportes los puedo generar sin problemas, pero cuando intento asignarle al parametro "ServerName" en mi código un nombre de servidor que contiene una direccion ip me arroja el siguente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La seguridad es integrada por lo que no requiero colocarle datos de acceso. la conexión con la base de datos se presenta sin problemas, pues puedo realizar procedimientos de guardado, eliminación y actualización, el problema surge al querer generar los reportes. a continuación un fragmento del código.

```
linea = objReader.ReadLine()
    Dim a As Integer = InStr(13, linea, "=", CompareMethod.Text) + 2
    Dim b As Integer = InStr(a, linea, ";", CompareMethod.Text)
    Dim dbase As String = Mid(linea, a, b - a)
    linea = objReader.ReadLine()
    objReader.Close()
    Dim crConInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim crLogInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    With crConInfo
        .ServerName = linea
        .DatabaseName = dbase '"Data"
        .IntegratedSecurity = True
        .Type = ConnectionInfoType.Query
    End With
    crLogInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConInfo
    Try
        Dim fechaInicio As String = Format(Date.Parse(txtFechaInicial.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim fechaFin As String = Format(Date.Parse(txtFechaFinal.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
        If cmbProceso.Text = "Despacho" Then
            If cmbReporteTipo.Text = "Simple" Then
                'Dim ReportePlanta As New objeto
                For Each tabla As Table In Objeto.Database.Tables
                    crLogInfo = tabla.LogOnInfo
                    crLogInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "192.30.1.29\MSSQLSERVER"
                    crLogInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = dbase
                    tabla.ApplyLogOnInfo(crLogInfo)
                Next
                Objeto.Refresh()
```

Al finalizar toda la operación termino con las siguientes líneas.

```
            Formulario.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Objeto
        Objeto.Refresh()
        If Formulario.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Formulario.Close()
        End If
```

Alguien me podría ayudar indicándome cual es el procedimiento adecuado para poder generar reportes desde una base de datos que se encuentre en un servidor?
De antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan suministrar.

Comment: Benkos, has puesto *en mi código un nombre de servidor que contiene una direccion ip me arroja el siguente error:* pero te olvidaste de colocar **el error.**

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso tuve el mismo problema y la solución la encontré fuera de visual studio.

Tienes que crear un archivo .dsn con el editor de texto de Windows e incluir en él los datos de acceso a la base de datos (servidor, nombre, password y usuario).

Posteriormente guardar el archivo dsn creado en la ruta:

- WINDOWS XP:

  > C:\Archivos de programas\Archivos comunes\ODBC\Data Sources
- WINDOWS 7 Y 8:

  - Para 32 bits:

    > C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ODBC\Data Sources
  - Para 64 bits:

    > C:\Program Files\Common Files\ODBC\Data Sources

Si no existen, crearlos.

Posteriormente añades el archivo dsn en:

> Herramientas del sistema/Administrador del orígenes de datos.

Te paso un enlace al documento que tengo de guía:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvft7rjiudkojbc/Configuraci%C3%B3n%20del%20sistema%20operativo2.docx?dl=0